# golddictonary and gnome 3

Tags: gnome

I'm very new to Linux . I just want to know that is it safe to install gnome3 in ubuntu 11.04 ?

my second question is about golden dictionary in ubuntu . I could not install off-line dictionary . I followed the video, downloaded the packages ,downloaded 7z too . I went to Babylon website there I downloaded dictionary in Hindi but they are in .exe file. I tried to extract .dsl file from .exe file but couldn't get them .I even didn't get the cab file from .exe file but nothing work for me ,

can anyone tells me how to install off-line dictionary ,or Hindi dictionary or link to get .dsl file,any open source Hindi dictionary ?
please help me, Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everybody out there 
the answer of my second question is that we can install Hindi dictionary in Ubuntu11.04
all you have to do is first install star dictionary from Ubuntu software center or using command apt-get install stardict or using synaptic.

After that u have to down load a  zip file name shabdanjali from INTERNET .
After downloading  shabdanjali zip extract the files u will have 3 or 4 file just copy those file into the "/usr/share/stardict/dic" folder.

after that go to star dictionary which will be in application/accessories/ menu .
In star dictionary click the home icon.
In this menu click the preferences and check the first option which is"only scan when the modiefier key is released " check this option

In this way u can have Hindi dictionary in Ubuntu 11.04
please pardon my spell mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

i think gnome3 is safe on ubuntu 11.10 but i don't know to ubuntu 11.04, in ubuntu 11.10 gnome3 is in the repositories but i don't know if is on ubuntu 11.04 repositories since if i remember correctly gnome 3 and them gnome 3.2 was release after ubuntu 11.04.however i am using currentlu ubuntu 12.04 beta and have gnome3 and i think is secure or at least only few bugs,.. but i don't know for sure..so if you use gnome3 update on ubuntu 11.10 i think is secure not sure on ubuntu 11.04

the second question i don't know ?if you installed from ubuntu software center the dictionary or from synaptic  and if so is working(if not try to reinstall) .. i don't know the application so i can not help more

Comment: thanx for replying .I installed dictionary from software centre . it will be great help if you can tell me how to get Hindi dictionary for ubuntu 11.04

Answer (score 0):

First, you can't use the Babylon dictionary as it is with the golden dict. You need to convert the Babylon dictionary to Stardict dictionary (Yes, it's not goldendict) format and then use it with Goldendict. Here is the [link](http://code.google.com/p/stardict-3/wiki/ConvertBabylon). Googling will give you lot of methods to this process.

How to get dictionary: 
Googling for stardict dictionary will give you link to download the dictionaries. I can't provide the links as those dictionaries are not legal.

Babylon dictionary:
Free Babylon app does not have any dictionary database with it. If you want to use the Babylon hindi dictionary, then you have purchase it. Once you have it you can open exe file with archiver in ubuntu and extract the BLG dictionary file, and follow my link to convert it to stardict format.

I hope this is helpful for you.